# Fade In/Out Multiple Images JQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a code like this.

```
<div id="all_sign">
<img src="images/sign1.jpg" id="sign1" />
<img src="images/sign2.jpg" id="sign2" />
<img src="images/sign3.jpg" id="sign3" />
<img src="images/sign4.jpg" id="sign4" />
<img src="images/sign5.jpg" id="sign5" />
</div>
```

The output should be like this first.
sign1.jpg     sign2.jpg    sign3.jpg    sign4.jpg    sign5.jpg

After loading all the five images,each image should fade out **randomly**(say for 2 seconds), and again it should fade in(after 2 seconds).

Hope this explanation is more than enough.

Thanks 
Haan

Comment: What have you done so far? What is your problem?

Comment: is one image over each other, or are positioned separately? and, do you need to loop? or animate just once?

Comment: @roXon - each image should fadein for 2 seconds. then fade-out. then again fadein. . . .. dont want to loop the images. this is a static content only

Comment: @ Emre Erkan - I have edited my question. Please check  it

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
$('#all_sign img').each(function(index){
   $(this).delay(index*1000).fadeIn(500,function(){ $(this).fadeOut(500); });
});
```